# Create akka message listener without extending Actor class

Tags: java, akka, listener

As I have seen from samples that one should be an actor in order to catch a message. But I need a custom listener in order to listen messages without creating a new actor class etc. I want something like this:

```
throw message

listen Response{
   ...
}
```

Any usage like that?

Thx

EDIT:  My purpose is to write a CEP and this CEP will need some business scenarios in order to produce outputs. So a scenario like this will occur:

Check if customer.internetusage>1000
check if quota exceeded
fraud check
...

This needs to be injected at runtime so I need a kind of structure in order to write a scenario like above.

Comment: Why would you want to create something that does what an `Actor` does but it is not an `Actor`?

Comment: Is creating an anonimous actor something you could live with?

Comment: Edited, please see

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to the event-bus. You just need to implement the traits defined here: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/event-bus.html